# Loading Data From MySQL to JavaScript Array of Array Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I have a php and jquery code like below

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var data =[];
    $("#submit").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"map.php",
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#message').html(html);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASS', '' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
  $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
  $query = "SELECT x,y FROM app";
  $results = $con->query($query);
  $return = array();
  if($results) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
      $return[] = array((float)$row['x'],(float)$row['y']);
    }
  }
   echo json_encode($return);
  $con->close();
 ?>
```

which return values from database like this in `$('#message').html(html);`

```
[ [ 20 , 20 ],[ 20 , 30 ],[ 50 , 35 ],[ 40 , 20 ] ]
```

How can I parse/export/push this result into `data =[];` to have an array of array there so eventually the result looks like this?

```
var data  =[ [ 20 , 20 ],[ 20 , 30 ],[ 50 , 35 ],[ 40 , 20 ] ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"map.php",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (html) {
         $('#message').html(html);
         data = html;
         console.log(data);
     }
});
```

Comment: Hi Romeo, Thanks for reply but is there any other way to see the actual result rather than console? because I am not sure what exactly i am getting  there with some numbers like 0:, 1:

Comment: You can see the true result if you open your Inspector / Firebug, the Network tab, then run that ajax and here in the tab you will see a new request. Click on it and on Preview you can see exactly what is sent from the server.

Comment: Thanks again, just for confirmation, so the structure of the data[] in reality looks like var data  =[ [ 20 , 20 ],[ 20 , 30 ],[ 50 , 35 ],[ 40 , 20 ] ]; right? I mean I am getting the correct result in console or alert(data.join('\n')); but to be honest the format of data[] is very important for me to since I am using this format to load circles to raphael.js paper so must be in that format exactly

Comment: Yes it has to be right. You can also check what you get with the others people solution: 

data = JSON.parse(html); or data = $.parseJSON(html);

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of your `json_encode` PHP function in Javascript is `JSON.parse(json)`:

```
var myArr = JSON.parse("[ [ 20 , 20 ],[ 20 , 30 ],[ 50 , 35 ],[ 40 , 20 ] ]");
```

Comment: @MonaCoder instead of `$('#message').html(html);` write `data = JSON.parse(html);`

Answer (score 0):

simple do

```
data  = $.parseJSON('[ [ 20 , 20 ],[ 20 , 30 ],[ 50 , 35 ],[ 40 , 20 ] ]');
```

or

data  = $.parseJSON(html);

NOTE: remove var while assigning array to data variable, it will assign the array to global data variable.

So final script will be:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var data =[];
    $("#submit").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType:'json',
                url:"map.php",
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#message').html(html);
                    data = $.parseJSON(html);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hi Sankalp, thanks for code but I am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"

Comment: can you paste more details about the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding - "dataType: "json" to your ajax call.. If you do this, json_encode in your php script will take care of returning proper array structure.

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"map.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (html) {
                $('#message').html(html);
            }
});
```

Comment: Hi pankaj thanks for reply now the result looks like 218.5149144,215.5990218219.2915206,216.8274247254.5833588,311.9862023254.2178971,314.9889649 so how can I add them to data[];

Comment: can you paste the output of var_dump($return) from your php script and also check if you are receiving proper json response by using some tool like - firebug..

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
echo json_encode($return);
you can use 
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$return));
to get response in associative array format.